# Android: Advertising ID vs. unique Android ID

Tags: android, uniqueidentifier, ads, mac-address, imei

Google is replacing the unique Android ID (similar to Apple’s old UDID) with a new [Advertising ID](http://marketingland.com/google-replacing-android-id-with-advertising-id-similar-to-apples-idfa-63636). Users will be able to reset the Advertising ID.

“Beginning August 1st 2014, all updates and new apps uploaded to the Play Store must use the advertising ID (when available on a device) in lieu of any other device identifiers for any advertising purposes.”

Is the Android ID no longer be available from August 2014? Can we use the Android ID for Non-Advertising. Can we use the IMEI or MAC Address after August 1st 2014?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is written "for any advertising purposes", it seems that you can continue to use Android ID, IMEI or MAC Address if it is not for advertisment.